# LinkedHashMap<String,Object>.clone();

Tags: java, clone

does the above command produce a deep copy of a LinkedHashMap's elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `clone()` is almost always shallow. This is for two reasons:

1. Performance
2. Not every object defines a working `clone()` method, so deep copying isn't always possible.

Comment: Unless overridden to do something else.

Answer (score 3):

`LinkedHashMap` derives from `HashMap`, which specifies this for the clone() method:

> Returns a shallow copy of this HashMap
>   instance: the keys and values
>   themselves are not cloned.

(So no, it's a shallow clone rather than deep. Not that it really matters for the strings.)